# which column family method is preferrable in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I want to create a Cassandra column family with the field(time_partition,key,period_time and period_value to store timeseries data.
i'm using time_partition is used for fast querying.
time_partition = period_time / (EPOCH OF A WEEK) ;

Which column family creation is better (I'm having lot of data too)?

Method 1

```
CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
  time_partition text,
  key text,
  period_time text,
  period_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (time_partition,key, period_time)
);
```

Method2

```
CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
  key text,
  time_partition text,  
  period_time text,
  period_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key,time_partition, period_time)
);
```

Difference between 2 methods are on the order of primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is** a difference. Your primary key defines how your data will be physically stored and hence the way how it can be queried.

The partition key (1st item in the primary key) will define the node on which node your data will be stored.

the following queries are valid for the 1st case (you can use other relations for non partition key beside of `=` as well).

```
select * from tablename where time_partition = <val>;
select * from tablename where time_partition = <val> and key = <val>;
select * from tablename where time_partition = <val> and key = <val> and period_time = <val>;
```

For the 2nd case those valid queries will be

```
select * from tablename where key = <val>;
select * from tablename where key = <val> and time_partition = <val>;
select * from tablename where key = <val> and time_partition = <val> and period_time = <val>;
```

You can't run `select * from tablename where key = <val>;` for 1st schema and `select * from tablename where time_partition = <val>;` for the 2nd

So model your tables based on your queries.

Comment: i want to only query like this:  
(for first method)select * from tablename where time_partition = <val> and key = <val> and period_time = <val>; or
(for second method) select * from tablename where key = <val> and time_partition = <val> and period_time = <val>; 
Is both have equal speed in fetching data?

Comment: The size of a partition can affect read performance as well. So if number of ``key``s is small then you'll end up with large partitions.

You can use compound partition key ``PRIMARY KEY ((key,time_partition), period_time)`` so each physical partition will only store ``period_time`` values. But you will not be able to order niether by ``key`` nor by ``time_partition``

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference. Order doesn't influence query speed.

Comment: What if number of 'key' fields are less and 'time_partition' is large?

Comment: it all depends what kind of query you are making. if you query by composite key, order doesn't matter at all.